# Change position of html element?

Tags: html, css

I am new to html and css. I am trying to move items around on a webpage. This is what the webpage looks like right now:

[image]

I have the following code for this webpage:

index.php:

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h2 id="loginText" style="top:383px" >Login</h2>
        <p id="credentialsText">Please fill in your credentials to login </p>
        <form id="formOverall" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username"class="form-control" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
            </div>    
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login">
            </div>
            <p>Don't have an account? <a href="register.php">Sign up now</a>.</p>
       </form>
    </div> 
</body>
```

However, all of the text still appears at the top left of the page. I want the text that says Login to appear further down in the page. That is why I have set style:"top: 383px". However, this text does not move from where it was before. How come this text does not move regardless of what I set in its style attribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`top` only works with certain `position` values.  Use a margin instead, like so:

```
<h2 id="loginText" style="margin-top:383px" >Login</h2>
```

This should work for what you need.  You can also move it to the right using `margin-left`, etc.

If you want to use `top`, you can do something like this:

```
<h2 id="loginText" style="position: absolute; top:383px" >Login</h2>
```

Absolute positioning lets you use `top`, `left`, `right`, and `bottom` to absolutely position elements on the page

You can read up more on the `position` property [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) and the `top` property [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_top.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Without the CSS it's hard to tell what the problem is, but my guess would be that you haven't declared a position attribute to the element, which means it defaults to `position: static`, meaning it won't move. So if you want to move the item you would need to declare `position: relative` and then apply the `top: 383px`. That being said, it is more common to just set `margin-top: 383px`. Again, if you add a copy of the CSS you're using it will be easier to address the issue.

Answer (score 0):

best positioning of your login form is to populate form in `<div>` . Than you can set to this div center (horizontaly) of screen by use style `margin: 0 auto;` and to vertical align, you can use some js or `margin-top:`, but use a % ... (dont forget to smaller screens than you have)

Answer (score -1):

make sure you define the position type.

```
<h2 id="loginText" style="top:383px; position:fixed" >Login</h2>
```

fixed means that the position (top:383px) is relative to the window. there are also other position types such as absolute, relative, or sticky.

Answer (score -1):

dude use `<div class="container m-5">` it will give your some margin from top and will create a container for you